# Query to calculate duedate..?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I want to generate due date for the Customer Renewal, based on the registration date,frequency.

What I would need: based on the date of signing the membership form and the frequency, I need a query to calculate the next date, when the customer needs to pay the membership amount. The day is always the same as the singing date's day, only the month and the year change.

Examples: if the contract signing date is 19/05/2007 then using sql query i should calculate the following 'next dates' (if calculated today):
monthly: 19/07/2009
quarterly: 19/08/2009
biannually: 19/11/2009
yearly: 19/05/2010

So how can i calculate his renewal due date using the **sql query**.
I am using SQLite database in my android application,will it be possible to do so.

Comment: Not all Androids are new enough to support CTEs, so this is better done in Java.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, SQLite is an internal database and may affect the reliability of the data consistency. You can use an alternative:
1. Create an API that stores users.
2. Provide an expiry duration within the storage database.
3.Send alerts and notification at real-time if the duration expires.
You can achieve using API's.